# Firefox. Menu doesn't work, few html elements such as dropdown list don't work too

Tags: firefox

A bit of preface. I have to use 32-bit Firefox on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 because of Cisco Webex. 
Browser I got from archive:

```
cd ~/32bit && wget -O firefox.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux&lang=en-US"
```

And run it with script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ENV_HOME=/home/sergius/32bit
export FIREFOX_HOME=$ENV_HOME/firefox
export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=$FIREFOX_HOME/plugins
export JDK_HOME=$ENV_HOME/jre1.7.0_80
export JAVA_HOME=$JDK_HOME/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JDK_HOME/bin:$PATH
$FIREFOX_HOME/firefox --no-remote -P 32bit
```

That's how I've managed to use Cisco Webex (I've googled a lot, only this works for me).
And now I have a trouble with browser itself. I noticed problem only yesterday, when tried to fill in html form and simple select object wasn't working. Then I saw, that firefox menu haven't worked at all (click, but nothing happens).

What I was tring to do:
1) moved ~/.mozilla to ~/.mozilla_backup and restart browser -  no changes
2) ran script with sudo - and everything became working again! What's wrong?

How to fix this problem?